# Zero-arg pattern matches when one arg expected

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Given this definition in Scala:

```
class Foo(val n: Int)

object Foo {
  def unapply(foo: Foo): Option[Int] = Some(foo.n)
}
```

This expression compiles and returns `ok`:

```
new Foo(1) match {
  case Foo() => "ok"
}
```

1. Why does this even compile? I would expect that an extractor with `Option[T]` implies matching patterns with exactly one argument only.
2. What does the pattern `Foo()` mean here? Is it equivalent to `Foo(_)`?

In other words, what is the language rule that enables the experienced behavior.

Comment: It seems to me that @wingedsubmariner is right, and scalac violates the spec. If no one comes up with an answer for this, maybe submit a bug report... https://issues.scala-lang.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today (in 2.11 milestone) you get the error:

```
<console>:15: error: wrong number of patterns for object Foo offering Int: expected 1, found 0
                case Foo() => "ok"
                     ^
```

I encountered this when adding `Regex.unapply(c: Char)`.  At some point, the case you point out was accepted, then later rejected.  I remember I liked the idea that if my extractor returns `Some(thing)`, then the Boolean match `case r()` would work the same as `case r(_)`.

What works is in the scaladoc of `unapply(Char)` :

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-master/library/#scala.util.matching.Regex

Comment: Indeed, scala-2.10.3 misbehaves while scala-2.11.0-M7 rejects the same code so I consider this a bug that is fixed in 2.11.

Answer (score 2):

Section 8.18 of [the Scala Language Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf) discusses this type of pattern matching. According to the reference, for a pattern like `Foo()`, it should only match if `unapply` returns a boolean. If `unapply` returns `Option[T]` for some T that isn't a tuple, then the pattern must include exactly one parameter, e.g. `Foo(_)`. Unless I'm really misunderstanding what is happening here, it looks like this is an edge case where the compiler violates the spec.